# Is there any chance that LGA771 Xeon CPU will work in LGA775 Systemboard without BIOS microcode update?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, lga775

My Systemboard is HP-DX2400MT - IPIBL-LB (MoBo) and it supports Pentium Dual Core/Core 2 Duo/Core 2 Quad CPUs. 
I want to buy any same spec Xeon CPU and I want to know if if it is possible or there is a change that it will work without microcode update?

Comment: If I am not mistaken then an LGA771 literally has seven hundred seventy one connection points and LGA775 has seven hundred seventy five connection points. Please point to the documentation which you read that says these sockets and CPUs are interchangeable with nothing more than a "microcode" update.

Comment: the topic i started is a well known issue. people do this but i want someone who really knows answer to my question. concerning my motherboard. The documentation is on wikipedia if you would like to know more >>> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I updated microcode and now running Xeon without problem.
It needs microcode update.